# Keras custom loss (chi2) linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am trying to implement a simple linear regression in Keras using a custom loss function.  I am calculating chi2 assuming the error is 1% of the function value.  I add 1% Gaussian noise to a linear model.  When I use the mean squared error loss function ('mse'), I can add the custom_loss() function as a metric, and I see that it converges to very close to 1 (chi2/ndf).  If I just use the custom_loss() directly as the loss function as shown in the snippet below, the neuron weight doesn't move at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred-y_true)/K.clip(K.square(0.01*y_pred), K.epsilon(), None), axis=-1)

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='linear'))

    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.01, nesterov=False)
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss=custom_loss, metrics=['mape', 'mse', custom_loss])
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':

    model = build_model()

    x_train = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 500)
    y_train = np.array(map(lambda x: x + 0.01*x*np.random.randn(1), x_train))

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, shuffle=True, epochs=1000, batch_size=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're trying to calculate with this loss, but here's what I see when I plot y_pred in [-1, 1], and y_true=0.5:

[Custom Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIKlK.png)

It's clearly got 2 minima, a very steep slope around 0 (undefined when y_pred=0) and low slope elsewhere.  Note that it's very easy for the network to go down the wrong "arm" of the loss function here.

Compare this loss against the squared error:

[MSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bygQd.png)

I would revisit your loss function: what are you trying to have the network learn here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am trying to train the network to predict points along the line (y = x) to within 1% accuracy.  I have tried to construct the chi2 function here and "by hand" inserted the uncertainty to be 1% of the true value (denom).  I also added a noise of 1% to the line.  When the network is predicting within 1% error, this custom_loss gives approximately 1. Mean-square error works great in this case, but in my real code the values of the function represented by y get very small.  So the network doesn't fit well in those areas.  I am trying avoid that problem.  Thanks